# Using server side set cookies, with server deleting them, still in subsequent requests

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, setcookie

I have an odd issue.  I've got an API with three endpoints /ping, /login, and /logout endpoints.  The `/login` sets a `token` cookie, `/logout` delete's the `token` cookie, and `/ping` just returns "pong".

The endpoints work like this:

POST /login
payload: username=bob&password=kidname

returns a `set-cookie: token=abcd; Path=/`

GET /logout
with `cookie: token=abcd` header
returns a `set-cookie: token=""; Path=/; Max-Age=0`

GET /ping
returns 'pong' in text/plain

When the user logins with /login, the `token` cookie gets set, and it's visible in `document.cookie` in the browser.  When the user logs out with /logout, the `token` cookie disappears from `document.cookie`, but it is still present in any subsequent requests to /ping.

I don't understand why the cookie is persisted in subsequent requests to the domain (in Chrome only, per chrome dev tools and server logs), even though the server "deleted" the cookie, and javascript shows the cookie deleted.  Firefox works as expected, but Chromium based browsers are dominant browsers today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a duplicate token cached and scoped under my /api path, which was overriding my / path cookie.